# How do i pass the ID of a row from my database to a modal dialog?

Tags: php, mysqli, modal-dialog

I have a modal dialog that i want it to display specific fields of a row in my database basing on the ID of that particular row. Im trying to pass the row ID from the database to the modal dialog so that i can use it for the query but im having challenges, how do i get this done?

```
 <?php

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_reservation ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo "<b><center><h3>Cars Reserved By Districts</h3></center></b><br><br>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $reservation_id = $row['reservation_id'];
    ?>

    <tr>
         <td><a  name="reserver"  data-id="myModal"  class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" >Reserver's Profile</a></td>

    </tr>

    <?php
$reserver = $row['reservation_id'];
    } //end of while loop ?>

    </tbody>
</table> 
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
             <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Reserver</center></h4>
            </div>
            <?php 
            $reserver = $row['reservation_id'];

        $reservation_id = 'reservation_id' ;
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_reservation WHERE reservation_id = '$reserver' ");
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                ?>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p ><strong>First Name: </strong><?php echo $row['fname'];?> </p><br>
        <p ><strong>Last Name: </strong><?php echo $row['lname'];?></p><br>
        <p ><strong>Mobile Number: </strong><?php echo $row['mobile_number'];?></p>
        </div>
        <?php } //end of while loop ?>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: you may want to use js for that.

Comment: @EmmanuelGamor, with your current approach even if you able to pass the id with js the next challenge is how to unload the data and load the the new data against new id without page referesh,

Comment: @Shehary i really thought of that but thinking if there would be other ways of achieving this same thing?

Comment: @EmmanuelGamor, there is a way but with your current approach it's not possible, I had the same issue i was trying the same way you are but it didn't work so I made some changes and it worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this same problem and I had tried jQuery dialog, many known and unknown popup plugins even paid one from codecanyon but nothing worked out of the box like bootstrap modal, with every popup plugin had to write custom code to work inside PHP while loop and then next problem is refresh the modal with new content without refreshing the page.

My approach with bootstrap modal is that i created a separate php file in your case `reservation-profile.php` and add the file in `href` link with `id` and call the popup modal.

```
<?php
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_reservation ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo "<b><center><h3>Cars Reserved By Districts</h3></center></b><br><br>";

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $reservation_id = $row['reservation_id'];
    ?>

    <tr><td>
     <a data-toggle="modal" href="reservation-profile.php?id=<?php echo $reservation_id;?>" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-link">Reserver's Profile</a>
    </td></tr>

<?php
    //$reserver = $row['reservation_id']; //Don't Need this
    } //end of while loop
?>

//Bootstrap Modal
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <strong>Loading...</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now create a `reservation-profile.php` file like this

```
<?php
//Include database connection here
$reserver = $_GET["id"]; //escape the string if you like
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM general_reservation WHERE reservation_id = '$reserver' ");
//$count = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Don't need to count the rows too
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); //Don't need the loop if you wana fetch only single row against id
?>
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Reserver</center></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <p ><strong>First Name: </strong><?php echo $row['fname'];?> </p><br>
    <p ><strong>Last Name: </strong><?php echo $row['lname'];?></p><br>
    <p ><strong>Mobile Number: </strong><?php echo $row['mobile_number'];?></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

The last and most important part is to refresh the modal with new detail without page refresh.

Following piece of code do the job. you can read more about it [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)
Note: Add following code to the page from where you are calling the modal. Do not add this in `reservation-profile.php`

```
//First jQuery Library
//Bootstrap Library
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
          $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    });
});
</script>
```

So this whole solution works out of the box no need to write any additional lines of code.

Comment: Thanks very much because i have been searching for a solution for a long time. But now, a challenge is the page has to be refreshed before i can call a different modal dialog by clicking on a different 'Reserver's Profile'. Now it loads only the modal dialog for the link which is clicked first after the page is refreshed.

Comment: I didn't get you, you need to refresh the page or the page refreshed itself while click the link or the modal open with same detail everytime?

Comment: I mean i need to refresh the page before a new model with different details can be seen other than that the modal opens the same detail everytime.

Comment: Its working perfectly now. What i did was i added a reload function to the close button on the modal dialog. `<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick="window.location.reload()">Close</button>`

Comment: @Shehary Nice answer.